# JRuby on Rails without a database

Tags: jruby, jrubyonrails

I'm kicking off a new Rails project in NetBeans using JRuby (v1.2.0) which uses Rails (2.3.2). I don't need a database, all my data comes from the cloud.

I've uncommented this line in my environment

config.frameworks -= [ :active_record, :active_resource, :action_mailer]

However, I still get the following errors just trying to call an action. Hosting on GlassFish.

java.net.SocketException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:156)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.(MysqlIO.java:276)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2666)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.(Connection.java:1531)

Any ideas where else I might need changes to not use a database?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

First step, make sure you dont have any environment specific overrides in config/environments/[your env].rb

I just did a test:

1. Create a new rails app
2. Edit config/environment.rb to
   uncomment the config.frameworks -= [
   :active_record, :active_resource,
   :action_mailer] line
3. jruby script/generate controller
   hello index
4. jruby script/server
5. Point browser at
   localhost:3000/hello

All seems ok - no ActiveRecord error.  How about for you?

Comment: This actually works, the difference is I was using GlassFish from inside NetBeans - if I run it outside using webrick as you did, then it works fine. This poses a problem however, when/if I put it into production on GlassFish then it would break again :(

Comment: Fair 'nuff...  Glassfish must be executing code paths that webrick or mongrel do not - but that doesn't make any sense to me...